# Problem creating a jwt auth for custom endpoint in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, jwt

I tried to create a custom momuser api with an endpoint using wp rest api the use4 registration endpoint worked well but i want to authenticate the mom user login endpoint using jwt with email and password as the parameters to use i found it difficult to get this work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Over! What did you try? Where is your code? You need to provide more details to see where you are stuck.

Comment: I was trying to make a wp rest api  custom endpoint and would like to authenticate it using jwt auth using email and password as the parameter but all i have been seeing is username and password

Comment: I actually created a user registration endpoint 
In worpress and i want to authenticate the login using jwt with email and password as the parameter.